# how to give the space between questions and answers in PHP.?

Tags: php

how to give the space between questions and answers in PHP.?

```
<tr><br><?php echo"1. your name:" . $row['name'];?></br></tr>"
<tr><br><?php echo"2. Age:" . $row['age'];?></br></tr>"
```

i need the output :

```
 Your Name        : Daz 
 Age              : 20
```

Comment: try **&nbsp;**.. and yes your html syntax is also messed up.

Comment: I think you need to go back to the basic HTML, your HTML syntax is messed up.

Comment: best to use some html element with class and add some css for those spaces, or use &nbsp;(5 to ten time for each). or just give space in the code itself after `your name:         `  (like this)

Comment: better to use tables

Comment: try this <tr><td><?php echo"1. your name:";?><td></td> <?=$row['name'];?><td></tr>

Comment: php shorttags ? :( we should not use shorttags @Dave

Comment: forget the table - use a dl-horizontal which will do that easily

Answer (score 2):

Follow a proper table convention:

```
<table>
   <tr>
     <th><?php echo "Your name:"; ?></th> 
     <td><?php echo $row['name'];?></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <th><?php echo "Age:"; ?></th> 
     <td><?php echo $row['age'];?></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Don't forget to escape the output from the database, which looks like it has user provided data in.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the perfect table structure so it will be easy for you i have setup an example please add the styling regarding you.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1. your name</td><td>:</td><td><?php echo $row['name'];?>/td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Don't forget to escape the output from the database, which looks like it has user provided data in.

Answer (score 0):

try this,
use `<td>` tag

```
    <tr>
     <th><?php echo "Your name"; ?></th> 
     <td><?php echo ":"; ?></td> 
     <td><?php echo $row['name'];?></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <th><?php echo "Age"; ?></th> 
     <td><?php echo ":"; ?></td>  
     <td><?php echo $row['age'];?></td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: Don't forget to escape the output from the database, which looks like it has user provided data in.

Answer (score 0):

You are opening a table row with `<tr>` but not writing any table cells `<td>`.

Try this:

```
<tr><td>1. your name:</td><td><?php echo htmlentities($row['name'], 'utf-8', ENT_QUOTES); ?></td></tr>
<tr><td>2. Age:</td><td><?php echo htmlentities($row['age'], 'utf-8', ENT_QUOTES); ?></td></tr>
```

I've taken the liberty of escaping the data from the database rows, never trust user input!